# React-Amin TabbedForm lose input when switch to next tab

Tags: react-admin

When using TabbedForm in `react-admin`, `Create` view will remove input value when switch tab. It doesn't happend with `Edit` view.

In redux state, `@@redux-form/INITIALIZE` action is the different between 2 views. Anyone has any idea why?

```
<Create {...props}>       
  <TabbedForm>
        <FormTab label="rate">
            <TextInput  source="name" label="Name"/>
            <NumberInput source="rate" label="Rate" defaultValue="0" />
        </FormTab>
        <FormTab label="score">
            <TextInput  source="score" label="Score"/>
            <NumberInput source="number" label="Number" defaultValue="0" />
        </FormTab>
  </TabbedForm>
</Create>
```

Comment: I also face the issue, this issue is because of `defaultValue`. Remove it and try.

Comment: What version are you using ? Would mind setting up a codesandbox reproducing the issue ?

Comment: This has been fixed some time ago. What version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.2.